# SQL aspx homework, stuck on doing a search advice?

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Hey all first post here.  I'm utterly lost on our assignment in my web database integration with c# course. My DB is a simple gradebook outlined below. The assignment is to search on an aspx page, and go to a search result page that show's in gridview the results of the DB query. We need to search for classes by department name and also a separate search page for searching by class name.

I know I have to join the tables somehow with sql, but can't recall how. I've been out sick playing catch up now that I'm back. Below is my DB outline, PK is primary KEY.

**Department**

```
DepartmentID PK  - linked to Table Class 1tomany
DepartmentName
```

**Class**

```
ClassID PK
ClassName
DepartmentID
CreditHours
```

I am lost when it comes to which page gets what datasources as well, the input search page with the txtbox for the search, or the search results page that has the results? Using Visual Studio and Microsoft Access as required by the course, thank you all!

EDIT Cindy was kind enough to help me on the inner join sql I was looking for, now if I can figure out the datasources I'm golden from there. Thanks Cindy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have several questions.  I can answer one of them.  But honestly, you'd be better off asking your teacher or a classmate for help.

To see all the classes and their department names,

```
SELECT ClassID, ClassName, CreditHours, class.DepartmentID, DepartmentName
FROM Class
INNER JOIN Department ON Department.DepartmentID = Class.DepartmentID
```

What this does is collect all the classes and connect them to their departments, matching ON the departmentID field that's stored as part of the class row.  Here's a good explanation.  https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6

Comment: Thank You Very Much!!!  This is enough to get me started.  I have been toying with the inner join after posting this.  This should help me move on to the next step of finding more on datasources. Thank you again!!

Comment: @mark, glad I could help!  Please mark the answer as the correct one and post any other questions as separate questions - each question is supposed to be only one question.  Thanks!